# Not able to run cqlsh command in apache cassandra

Tags: python, java, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have installed apache cassandra and i checked my java versions as well.

```
java -version
openjdk version "11.0.10" 2021-01-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 11.0.10+9, mixed mode)
```

However, after going into bin file and trying to run `./cqlsh` or `./cassandra -f` I am getting this error:

> bin % .**/cassandra -f
> [0.003s][warning][gc] -Xloggc is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:gc:./../logs/gc.log instead.
> intx ThreadPriorityPolicy=42 is outside the allowed range [ 0 ... 1 ]
> Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Answer (score 0):

> Improperly specified VM option 'ThreadPriorityPolicy=42'

`-XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42` is specified in the `conf/jvm.options` file.  That file was built with flags specific to Java 8, because that is the highest level of the JDK supported by Apache Cassandra 3.

There are two options here:

- Upgrade to Cassandra 4.0, which *will* run on Java 11.
- Downgrade the JDK to (the latest patch of) Java 8.